# Problemas no retorno de um JSONP

Tags: ajax, jsonp

Pessoal tou tentando pegar uma resposta de uma API minha como JSONP mas não da certo.
Codigo ajax é este:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            complete: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Retorno é este do console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a resposta de retorno do AJAX:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para recuperar estes valores no JQuery?

Obrigado

Comment: `var codigo = data[0].codigo`?

Comment: @Sergio deu o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'codigo' of undefined

Comment: Ok, e o que dá `console.log(typeof data, data);`?

Comment: @Sergio da a resposta que esta na primeria imagem que enviei ai na dúvida.

Comment: Em vez de `complete: function(data) {` testa com `success: function(data) {`

Comment: @Sergio o estranho também é isto ele não entra no success apenas no error, mesmo o cabeçalho informando status code 200 conforme a primeira imagem mostra. ja não estou sabendo o que fiz de errado. O duro que por exemplo se eu usar o POSTMAN e acessar o mesmo endereço da API volta tudo certinho. Pode ser por que estou rodando localmente e acessando uma URL externa?

Comment: E tens a certeza que é jsonp? a resposta parece-me json... testa             dataType: 'json',

Comment: Com o JSON da o seguinte erro: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://testejn.hospedagemdesites.ws/api/bairros/16. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. Tente acessar via POSTMAN esta URL e você vera que esta certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            complete: function(data) {
                console.log(data[0].atributo);
            }
        });
```

Ou se retornou uma String como JSON:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            complete: function(data) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
                console.log(obj[0].atributo);                    
            }
        });
```

Para pegar todos os atributos de cada array basta fazer um simples for.

Comment: Nenhum dos exemplos deu certo veja os erros:
No primeiro exemplo da este erros: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'atributo' of undefined
Nos segundo exemplo da o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: amigo olha postei ai as imagens da depuração do AJAX veja se você consegue me ajudar. Obrigado

Comment: Substitua `atributo` pelos atributos que vem do objeto, exemplo: `bairro`, `cod_cidade`. O `atributo` que coloquei na minha resposta foi somente como exemplo. Utilize o primeiro exemplo que lhe passei que irá funcionar.

Comment: olha estou usando o seu primeiro exemplo e o erro que da quando eu coloco console.log(data[0].codigo) por exemplo é este: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'codigo' of undefined e se eu dou um console apenas no data[0] da undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Usa `contentType: "text/plain",`.

```
var url = 'http://testejn.hospedagemdesites.ws/api/bairros/16';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    contentType: "text/plain",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data[0]);
    }
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9p65b280/1/